# how to add quality or some coustem control for this video player

Tags: javascript, html

The video needs quality
Then when full screen is turned on, the video controls will not be hide
Video controls can be hide when full screen
and video detection through control

```js
const playPauseBtn = document.querySelector(".play-pause-btn")
const theaterBtn = document.querySelector(".theater-btn")
const fullScreenBtn = document.querySelector(".full-screen-btn")
const miniPlayerBtn = document.querySelector(".mini-player-btn")
const muteBtn = document.querySelector(".mute-btn")
const captionsBtn = document.querySelector(".captions-btn")
const speedBtn = document.querySelector(".speed-btn")
const currentTimeElem = document.querySelector(".current-time")
const totalTimeElem = document.querySelector(".total-time")
const previewImg = document.querySelector(".preview-img")
const thumbnailImg = document.querySelector(".thumbnail-img")
const volumeSlider = document.querySelector(".volume-slider")
const videoContainer = document.querySelector(".video-container")
const timelineContainer = document.querySelector(".timeline-container")
const video = document.querySelector("video")

document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  const tagName = document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase()

  if (tagName === "input") return

  switch (e.key.toLowerCase()) {
    case " ":
      if (tagName === "button") return
    case "k":
      togglePlay()
      break
    case "f":
      toggleFullScreenMode()
      break
    case "t":
      toggleTheaterMode()
      break
    case "i":
      toggleMiniPlayerMode()
      break
    case "m":
      toggleMute()
      break
    case "arrowleft":
    case "j":
      skip(-5)
      break
    case "arrowright":
    case "l":
      skip(5)
      break
    case "c":
      toggleCaptions()
      break
  }
})

// Timeline
timelineContainer.addEventListener("mousemove", handleTimelineUpdate)
timelineContainer.addEventListener("mousedown", toggleScrubbing)
document.addEventListener("mouseup", e => {
  if (isScrubbing) toggleScrubbing(e)
})
document.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  if (isScrubbing) handleTimelineUpdate(e)
})

let isScrubbing = false
let wasPaused
function toggleScrubbing(e) {
  const rect = timelineContainer.getBoundingClientRect()
  const percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, e.x - rect.x), rect.width) / rect.width
  isScrubbing = (e.buttons & 1) === 1
  videoContainer.classList.toggle("scrubbing", isScrubbing)
  if (isScrubbing) {
    wasPaused = video.paused
    video.pause()
  } else {
    video.currentTime = percent * video.duration
    if (!wasPaused) video.play()
  }

  handleTimelineUpdate(e)
}

function handleTimelineUpdate(e) {
  const rect = timelineContainer.getBoundingClientRect()
  const percent = Math.min(Math.max(0, e.x - rect.x), rect.width) / rect.width
  const previewImgNumber = Math.max(
    1,
    Math.floor((percent * video.duration) / 10)
  )
  const previewImgSrc = `assets/previewImgs/preview${previewImgNumber}.jpg`
  previewImg.src = previewImgSrc
  timelineContainer.style.setProperty("--preview-position", percent)

  if (isScrubbing) {
    e.preventDefault()
    thumbnailImg.src = previewImgSrc
    timelineContainer.style.setProperty("--progress-position", percent)
  }
}

// Playback Speed
speedBtn.addEventListener("click", changePlaybackSpeed)

function changePlaybackSpeed() {
  let newPlaybackRate = video.playbackRate + 0.25
  if (newPlaybackRate > 2) newPlaybackRate = 0.25
  video.playbackRate = newPlaybackRate
  speedBtn.textContent = `${newPlaybackRate}x`
}

// Captions
const captions = video.textTracks[0]
captions.mode = "hidden"

captionsBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleCaptions)

function toggleCaptions() {
  const isHidden = captions.mode === "hidden"
  captions.mode = isHidden ? "showing" : "hidden"
  videoContainer.classList.toggle("captions", isHidden)
}

// Duration
video.addEventListener("loadeddata", () => {
  totalTimeElem.textContent = formatDuration(video.duration)
})

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", () => {
  currentTimeElem.textContent = formatDuration(video.currentTime)
  const percent = video.currentTime / video.duration
  timelineContainer.style.setProperty("--progress-position", percent)
})

const leadingZeroFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat(undefined, {
  minimumIntegerDigits: 2,
})
function formatDuration(time) {
  const seconds = Math.floor(time % 60)
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60) % 60
  const hours = Math.floor(time / 3600)
  if (hours === 0) {
    return `${minutes}:${leadingZeroFormatter.format(seconds)}`
  } else {
    return `${hours}:${leadingZeroFormatter.format(
      minutes
    )}:${leadingZeroFormatter.format(seconds)}`
  }
}

function skip(duration) {
  video.currentTime += duration
}

// Volume
muteBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleMute)
volumeSlider.addEventListener("input", e => {
  video.volume = e.target.value
  video.muted = e.target.value === 0
})

function toggleMute() {
  video.muted = !video.muted
}

video.addEventListener("volumechange", () => {
  volumeSlider.value = video.volume
  let volumeLevel
  if (video.muted || video.volume === 0) {
    volumeSlider.value = 0
    volumeLevel = "muted"
  } else if (video.volume >= 0.5) {
    volumeLevel = "high"
  } else {
    volumeLevel = "low"
  }

  videoContainer.dataset.volumeLevel = volumeLevel
})

// View Modes
theaterBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleTheaterMode)
fullScreenBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleFullScreenMode)
miniPlayerBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleMiniPlayerMode)

function toggleTheaterMode() {
  videoContainer.classList.toggle("theater")
}

function toggleFullScreenMode() {
  if (document.fullscreenElement == null) {
    videoContainer.requestFullscreen()
  } else {
    document.exitFullscreen()
  }
}

function toggleMiniPlayerMode() {
  if (videoContainer.classList.contains("mini-player")) {
    document.exitPictureInPicture()
  } else {
    video.requestPictureInPicture()
  }
}

document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", () => {
  videoContainer.classList.toggle("full-screen", document.fullscreenElement)
})

video.addEventListener("enterpictureinpicture", () => {
  videoContainer.classList.add("mini-player")
})

video.addEventListener("leavepictureinpicture", () => {
  videoContainer.classList.remove("mini-player")
})

// Play/Pause
playPauseBtn.addEventListener("click", togglePlay)
video.addEventListener("click", togglePlay)

function togglePlay() {
  video.paused ? video.play() : video.pause()
}

video.addEventListener("play", () => {
  videoContainer.classList.remove("paused")
})

video.addEventListener("pause", () => {
  videoContainer.classList.add("paused")
})
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.video-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-inline: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

.video-container.theater,
.video-container.full-screen {
  max-width: initial;
  width: 100%;
}

.video-container.theater {
  max-height: 90vh;
}

.video-container.full-screen {
  max-height: 100vh;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
}

.video-controls-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.video-controls-container::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .75), transparent);
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 6 / 1;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.video-container:hover .video-controls-container,
.video-container:focus-within .video-controls-container,
.video-container.paused .video-controls-container {
  opacity: 1;
}

.video-controls-container .controls {
  display: flex;
  gap: .5rem;
  padding: .25rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.video-controls-container .controls button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .85;
  transition: opacity 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.video-controls-container .controls button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.video-container.paused .pause-icon {
  display: none;
}

.video-container:not(.paused) .play-icon {
  display: none;
}

.video-container.theater .tall {
  display: none;
}

.video-container:not(.theater) .wide {
  display: none;
}

.video-container.full-screen .open {
  display: none;
}

.video-container:not(.full-screen) .close {
  display: none;
}

.volume-high-icon,
.volume-low-icon,
.volume-muted-icon {
  display: none;
}

.video-container[data-volume-level="high"] .volume-high-icon {
  display: block;
}

.video-container[data-volume-level="low"] .volume-low-icon {
  display: block;
}

.video-container[data-volume-level="muted"] .volume-muted-icon {
  display: block;
}

.volume-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.volume-slider {
  width: 0;
  transform-origin: left;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: width 150ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease-in-out;
}

.volume-container:hover .volume-slider,
.volume-slider:focus-within {
  width: 100px;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.duration-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: .25rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.video-container.captions .captions-btn {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}

.video-controls-container .controls button.wide-btn {
  width: 50px;
}

.timeline-container {
  height: 7px;
  margin-inline: .5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.timeline {
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, .5);
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative
}

.timeline::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: calc(100% - var(--preview-position) * 100%);
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
  display: none;
}

.timeline::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: calc(100% - var(--progress-position) * 100%);
  background-color: red;
}

.timeline .thumb-indicator {
  --scale: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%) scale(var(--scale));
  height: 200%;
  top: -50%;
  left: calc(var(--progress-position) * 100%);
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: transform 150ms ease-in-out;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}

.timeline .preview-img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 80px;
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
  top: -1rem;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  left: calc(var(--preview-position) * 100%);
  border-radius: .25rem;
  border: 2px solid white;
  display: none;
}

.thumbnail-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.video-container.scrubbing .thumbnail-img {
  display: block;
}

.video-container.scrubbing .preview-img,
.timeline-container:hover .preview-img {
  display: block;
}

.video-container.scrubbing .timeline::before,
.timeline-container:hover .timeline::before {
  display: block;
}

.video-container.scrubbing .thumb-indicator,
.timeline-container:hover .thumb-indicator {
  --scale: 1;
}

.video-container.scrubbing .timeline,
.timeline-container:hover .timeline {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="video-container paused" data-volume-level="high">
    <img class="thumbnail-img">
    <div class="video-controls-container">
      <div class="timeline-container">
        <div class="timeline">
          <img class="preview-img">
          <div class="thumb-indicator"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="controls">
        <button class="play-pause-btn">
          <svg class="play-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path fill="currentColor" d="M8,5.14V19.14L19,12.14L8,5.14Z" />
          </svg>
          <svg class="pause-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path fill="currentColor" d="M14,19H18V5H14M6,19H10V5H6V19Z" />
          </svg>
        </button>
        <div class="volume-container">
          <button class="mute-btn">
            <svg class="volume-high-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path fill="currentColor" d="M14,3.23V5.29C16.89,6.15 19,8.83 19,12C19,15.17 16.89,17.84 14,18.7V20.77C18,19.86 21,16.28 21,12C21,7.72 18,4.14 14,3.23M16.5,12C16.5,10.23 15.5,8.71 14,7.97V16C15.5,15.29 16.5,13.76 16.5,12M3,9V15H7L12,20V4L7,9H3Z" />
            </svg>
            <svg class="volume-low-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path fill="currentColor" d="M5,9V15H9L14,20V4L9,9M18.5,12C18.5,10.23 17.5,8.71 16,7.97V16C17.5,15.29 18.5,13.76 18.5,12Z" />
            </svg>
            <svg class="volume-muted-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
              <path fill="currentColor" d="M12,4L9.91,6.09L12,8.18M4.27,3L3,4.27L7.73,9H3V15H7L12,20V13.27L16.25,17.53C15.58,18.04 14.83,18.46 14,18.7V20.77C15.38,20.45 16.63,19.82 17.68,18.96L19.73,21L21,19.73L12,10.73M19,12C19,12.94 18.8,13.82 18.46,14.64L19.97,16.15C20.62,14.91 21,13.5 21,12C21,7.72 18,4.14 14,3.23V5.29C16.89,6.15 19,8.83 19,12M16.5,12C16.5,10.23 15.5,8.71 14,7.97V10.18L16.45,12.63C16.5,12.43 16.5,12.21 16.5,12Z" />
            </svg>
          </button>
          <input class="volume-slider" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="any" value="1">
        </div>
        <div class="duration-container">
          <div class="current-time">0:00</div>
          /
          <div class="total-time"></div>
        </div>
        <button class="captions-btn">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path fill="currentColor" d="M18,11H16.5V10.5H14.5V13.5H16.5V13H18V14A1,1 0 0,1 17,15H14A1,1 0 0,1 13,14V10A1,1 0 0,1 14,9H17A1,1 0 0,1 18,10M11,11H9.5V10.5H7.5V13.5H9.5V13H11V14A1,1 0 0,1 10,15H7A1,1 0 0,1 6,14V10A1,1 0 0,1 7,9H10A1,1 0 0,1 11,10M19,4H5C3.89,4 3,4.89 3,6V18A2,2 0 0,0 5,20H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,18V6C21,4.89 20.1,4 19,4Z" />
          </svg>
        </button>
        <button class="speed-btn wide-btn">
          1x
        </button>
        <button class="mini-player-btn">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path fill="currentColor" d="M21 3H3c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h18c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm0 16H3V5h18v14zm-10-7h9v6h-9z"/>
          </svg>
        </button>
        <button class="theater-btn">
          <svg class="tall" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path fill="currentColor" d="M19 6H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v8c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V8c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm0 10H5V8h14v8z"/>
          </svg>
          <svg class="wide" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path fill="currentColor" d="M19 7H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v6c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V9c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zm0 8H5V9h14v6z"/>
          </svg>
        </button>
        <button class="full-screen-btn">
          <svg class="open" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path fill="currentColor" d="M7 14H5v5h5v-2H7v-3zm-2-4h2V7h3V5H5v5zm12 7h-3v2h5v-5h-2v3zM14 5v2h3v3h2V5h-5z"/>
          </svg>
          <svg class="close" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path fill="currentColor" d="M5 16h3v3h2v-5H5v2zm3-8H5v2h5V5H8v3zm6 11h2v-3h3v-2h-5v5zm2-11V5h-2v5h5V8h-3z"/>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <video src="assets/Video.mp4">
      <track kind="captions" srclang="en" src="assets/subtitles.vtt">
    </video>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The video needs quality
Then when full screen is turned on, the video controls will not be hide
Video controls can be hide when full screen
and video detection through control

Comment: Pls provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)